# ASP MVC conditionally display text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, label

How would I alter the code below to not display the label is there is no text for the '@Html.DisplayTextFor' to show?

```
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TableName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.TableName)                
        </div>
```

This is for an ASP MVC3 web page.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use a conditional

```
@if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.TableName))
{
  <div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TableName)
  </div>
  <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.TableName)                
  </div>
}
```